# vis.js Graph2d data points multiple selection and line draw

Tags: vis.js

Am using the latest vis.js library for my charting needs.

I want to select multiple data points on Graph2d scatter chart and draw a line amongst the selected data points to signify a pattern.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph2d doesn't support selecting data points. You could create a feature request for this in the issues section of the project: https://github.com/almende/vis/issues